# crockjs and apply functions need a function as value

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm actually learning functional programming, and I'm trying to learn & use [crockjs](https://evilsoft.github.io/crocks/docs/getting-started.html)

For now, I'm trying to implement the "monadster" program described in https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/monadster/ .

Here's what I'm having for now (just the beginning...)

```
const State = require("crocks/State");

const LivingPart = (unitOfForce, deadThing) => ({ unitOfForce, deadThing });

// Creating the potential living thing
const makeLiveThingM = deadThing => {
  const becomeAlive = vitalForce => {
    const unitOfForce = 1;
    const remaining = vitalForce - unitOfForce;

    return { part: LivingPart(unitOfForce, deadThing), remaining };
  };

  return State.get(becomeAlive);
};

// Using containers
const deadLegM = makeLiveThingM("deadLeg");
const deadArmM = makeLiveThingM("deadArm");

const livingThings = deadLegM.ap(deadArmM).evalWith(1);

console.log(livingThings);
```

My problem is that it throws the following error:

```
/Users/pc/Soft/experiments/functional/crocks/node_modules/crocks/State/index.js:101
        throw new TypeError('State.ap: Source value must be a function')
        ^

TypeError: State.ap: Source value must be a function
```

From what I see there, it's probably because I don't understand the apply function, or the way `State.get` is running. For me it accepts a function as its internal value in my code, but it doesn't seem so.

Can anybody explains and show me what I'm doing wrong here ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to functional programming in JS and thank you for giving `crocks` a shot.

In looking at that article, one of the things to note is that the author is presenting how the mechanics work inside of the `State` ADT, and not really how to use an existing `State` ADT.

I will provide an explanation on how to handle the `State` transactions manually, which is close to what you have in your implementation. Then I will give a brief example of how the construction helpers (like `get` and `modify` could be used to decrement the `VitalForce`) are used to handle the and build `State` transactions.

Also I will give a brief explanation of using `Applicative`s.

So to start lets bring in a couple ADTs from `crocks`

```
const Pair = require('crocks/Pair')
const State = require('crocks/State')
```

We need the State constructor to take in a function that will return a `Pair` (the tuple that the author mentions in the post). How the construction function works can be found [here](https://evilsoft.github.io/crocks/docs/crocks/State.html#topic-construction).

Before we can discuss the State function, we need that `LivingPart` function:

```
// LivingPart :: (Integer, String) -> Object
const LivingPart = (unitOfForce, part) =>
  ({ [part]: { unitOfForce } })
```

I have changed the structure from what you originally had so we could merge any given `Part` together with another.

Now with that bit in the mix we can implement `makeLiveThing`. You pretty much had it in your implementation. The only real difference here is we need to construct the `State` ADT with the function and return the `Pair`. Notice that we still bring in the `String`, BUT return a `State` ADT that will be executed when `runWith` is called. Remember that the current state will be passed into the function that the `State` instance wraps (in this case, `vitalForce` is our state):

```
// makeLiveThing :: String -> State Integer Object
const makeLiveThing = part => State(
  vitalForce => {
    const unitOfForce = 1
    const remaining = vitalForce - unitOfForce

    return Pair(
      LivingPart(unitOfForce, part),
      remaining
    )
  }
)
```

Now that we have a means to create a `LivingPart` and handle our state transaction (decrementing by 1), we can create a couple parts:

```
// rightLeg :: State Integer Object
const rightLeg =
  makeLiveThing('right-leg')

// leftArm :: State Integer Object
const leftArm =
  makeLiveThing('left-arm')
```

Now comes the task of joining these `State` instances. You were right to think to use `apply`, as when an ADT has both an `ap` method and an `of` method it is called an `Applicative`. When we have an `Applicative` we can think of the type as being able to combine (2) independent instances that do not depend on the result of the other one. We just need to provide a way to tell the type how to combine it.

Typically that is done with a function that can act on the types contained in the ADT. In our case it is an `Object`, so one way to combine (2) objects is with `Object.assign`. `crocks` provides a helper called `assign` that can do just that, so lets bring it in:

```
const assign = require('crocks/helpers/assign')
```

Now that we have a way to combine the internal values, we need to "lift" this function into our `State` type, `crocks` also has a function that can be used on `Applicative`s to lift and apply the internal values of ADT (2) instances called `liftA2`. Which means "lift a function into an applicative with 2 instances"

So lets bring that in as well and then create a function that will be used to join (2) `Parts`:

```
const liftA2 = require('crocks/helpers/liftA2')


// joinParts :: Applicative m => m Object -> m Object -> m Object
const joinParts =
  liftA2(assign)
```

Now with this function we can lift and join those parts and run the result with our `VitalForce`:

```
joinParts(rightLeg, leftArm)
  .runWith(10)
//=> Pair( { left-arm: { unitOfForce: 1 }, right-leg: { unitOfForce: 1 } }, 8 )
```

Notice the result has the resultant in the left (the combined living parts) and the state in the right (the remaining `VitalForce`).

Here are some references to that above:

- [`assign` function](https://evilsoft.github.io/crocks/docs/functions/helpers.html#assign)
- [`liftA2` function](https://evilsoft.github.io/crocks/docs/functions/helpers.html#lifta2)
- [`State` ADT](https://evilsoft.github.io/crocks/docs/crocks/State.html)
- [`Pair` ADT](https://evilsoft.github.io/crocks/docs/crocks/Pair.html)
- [egghead course on the `State` API](https://egghead.io/courses/state-monad-in-javascript)

Now I am going to show a brief example of how we can set up a single `State` transaction for taking `VitalForce` from our pool. I am not going to explain here in detail, but you *should* be able to glean some information between this example and the `State` documentation:

```
const State = require('crocks/State')

const constant = require('crocks/combinators/constant')
const mapProps = require('crocks/helpers/mapProps')

const { modify } = State

// decrementBy :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
const decrementBy =
  x => y => y - x

// VitalForce :: { units: Integer }

// decUnitsBy :: Integer -> VitalForce -> VitalForce
const decUnitsBy = units =>
  mapProps({ units: decrementBy(units) })

// getVitalForce :: Integer -> State VitalForce VitalForce
const getVitalForce = units =>
  modify(decUnitsBy(units))
    .map(constant({ units }))

getVitalForce(3)
  .runWith({ units: 10 })
//=> Pair( { units: 3 }, { units: 7 } )
```

Here are some docs for those included functions:

- [`constant` function](https://evilsoft.github.io/crocks/docs/functions/combinators.html#constant)
- [`mapProps` function](https://evilsoft.github.io/crocks/docs/functions/helpers.html#mapprops)

So as a side note, I do a LiveCode broadcast [on this channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/TheEvilSoft), I am going to go over this blog post and talk about how to implement this in `crocks`, if that is something you would be interested in.

Hope this helps!!